# C++ Copy constructor & Operators

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, constructor, copy-constructor

I'm currently preparing for my exam in C++, and today i came  across the following problem:

Given the following program:

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;
class A
{
private:
    int x, y;
public:
    A(int X = 0, int Y = 0) :x(X), y(Y) 
    {
        cout << "A Constructor" << endl;
    }
    A(A& a) 
    {
        x = a.x; y = a.y;  
        cout << "A Copy Constructor" << endl;  
    }
    A operator+(A a) 
    {
        A tmp(*this);  
        tmp.x += a.x;
        tmp.y += a.y;
        return tmp;
    }
    A& operator=(A& a)
    { 
         x = a.x;
         y = a.y;   
         return *this; 
    }
};
int main()
{
    A a(1, 2), b(3, 4), c; 
    c = a + b; 
    system("pause");
    return 0; 
}
```

Which of the following will be the output of the program?

**1)**

A Constructor
A Constructor
A Constructor
A Copy Constructor
A Copy Constructor
A Copy Constructor

**2)**

A Constructor
A Constructor
A Constructor
A Copy Constructor
A Copy Constructor
A Copy Constructor
A Copy Constructor

**3)**

A Constructor
A Constructor
A Constructor
A Copy Constructor

**4)**

A Constructor
A Constructor
A Copy Constructor
A Copy Constructor
A Copy Constructor

This is a question from the past year exam, and the problem is, that when i run the above code in Visual C++ 2017, it gives an error like you can see in the picture:

[image]

And it says: **no operator "=" matches these operands, operand types are: A = A**.

I realized what's wrong in the code, and found that the **operator+** Method should be like this:

```
A& operator+(A& a)
```

Instead of

```
A operator+(A a)
```

But the semester is over, and i have no one to ask, so i come here.
I don't know exactly which version of VC++ was used in the past year exam,
and because an option of error is not included in the answer options, i understand (maybe) that this code was valid in an earlier version of C++. but my questions are:

Do this error comes from the differences between the versions of C++?

What is the major difference between the above two versions of **operator+** method?

Are the **operator+** and **operator=** methods must have the same return type (i mean by reference or by value)?

Is the parameter of the **operator+** and **operator=** methods must be the same like the parameter of the Copy Constructor?

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!!

Comment: The short answer would be: run it through a compiler and see the output on the standard output. This is just too broad. One question per question please. As a sidenote your teacher / professor should be aware that `using namespace std;` is bad practice and we no longer need to `return 0;` in the main function. And `system("pause");` is dubious too.

Comment: The code you show is invalid, as Visual Studio kindly tells you. It seems like your professor haven't tested it properly, or tested it using a compiler which let the error slip through.

Comment: This code is incorrect. If you fix the `const` problems, the output will depend on the version of c++ and what flags you are using. There are some copy elision possibilities which is a type of optimization that is exceptionally allowed to alter the observable behavior of a program.

Comment: `operator+` should definitively not be `A& operator+(A& a)`. What would you return? If you return either `a` or `*this` it implies you modified one of your operands, which the operator is not expected to do. If you try to return a local variable, you will be returning a reference to an object that no longer exists. The problem is solved by a liberal application of `const`.

Comment: I would expect `A(const A& a)` and If you're learning modern C++, I would also expect there to be a `A(A&& a)` move constructor. But anyhow.

Comment: Visual Studio didn't accept this code last year either. It has warned about its own "non-standard extension" for quite some time now. Perhaps last years exam recycled questions from even older exams?

Answer (score 3):

In Standard C++, all of the suggested answers are wrong. The actual behaviour is that the code fails to compile due to the line:

```
c = a + b;
```

The right hand side has value category *prvalue*. The `operator=` function takes `A&` as parameter, and a prvalue cannot bind to a non-const lvalue reference.

BTW your comment

> the operator+ Method should be like this: `A& operator+(A& a)`

is wrong. The actual definition of `operator+` is correct. The mistakes are the copy-constructor and the assignment-operator, they should take `A const&`.

---

Possibly the exam refers to Microsoft's non-standard language dialect in which a prvalue can bind to an lvalue reference of the same type.

Comment: Indeed, this again proves professors are just people, thus they can make mistakes ;)